# Why do we need to wrap IIFE with ()

Tags: javascript, function, iife

When we use a standalone function statement as IIFE we need to wrap it with`()` to make it work

```js
// IFFE
(function a(){
    console.log('Hello')
}());

// IFFE
(function a(){
    console.log('Hello')
})()
```

If we don't wrap with `()` code produces a syntax error

```js
function a(){
    console.log('Hello')
}()
```

But when we use as function expression we do not need to wrap it with `()`

```js
let a = function a(){
    console.log('Hello')
}()
```

So why we need to wrap it with `()` when we want to use it as function statement ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the interpreter is parsing the Javascript text, when it comes across a new line and `function a`, it will start interpreting that as a function declaration for a function named `a`. Eventually, it will come to the end of the function block with `}`. If you put a `()` after that, it will attempt to parse the `(` as the start of an expression - but an expression has to evaluate to *something*, it can't be empty, so when it sees `)`, it throws.

(you *can* put something in the parentheses, but it'll just be an unused expression, and the function won't be invoked:

```js
function foo() {
  console.log('foo');
}(123);

console.log('done');
```

)

Putting `(` before the `function a` ensures that the interpreter parses the `function a` that follows as an *expression* (a value that can be used, like by the `()` that comes later), rather than a statement (which *does* something - like declare the function available in that scope - but does not evaluate to a value).

Comment: I wasn't expecting such a concise answer but that makes a ton of sense! Putting `(a())` in the "invocation" call in the 2nd snippet behaves the same as the last (3rd) snippet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer mate :) so i can use anything which makes parse to read it as expression something like `[function a(){}()]`

Comment: Yep, could even do something silly like `7 + function a(){ console.log('x')}()`